# Tracking Protection lists for IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, privacy-protection

Is it possible to make your own Tracking Protection lists for IE 9 or modify the excisting lists supplied by easylist from AdBlock Plus

Comment: If Adblock Plus a third-party can modify the tracking protection list and include its own data it must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

> To manage your existing Tracking Protection List subscriptions, click the gear icon in the top-right corner of IE9, mouse over safety, and then click Tracking Protection Lists. You can then disable or remove active lists, **or use the personal list to add your own custom blocking rules.**

.

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/02/14/how-to-use-internet-explorer-9-tracking-protection-lists/

.

Seems to be another half baked implementation of a good idea by Microsoft.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906091135/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/12/07/ie9-and-privacy-introducing-tracking-protection-v8.aspx)

Ed Bott does a good job of explaining IE9 tracking protection

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/privacy-protection-and-ie9-who-can-you-trust/3014

.

To access any of the lists you have installed click the gear on the upper right corner of IE and select Safety > Tracking Protection.

.